# Getting started with databases for UWP and WPF: Roadmap needed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, entity-framework

I know general, less specific questions aren't ideal. But I'm a beginner and are pretty confused about how I get started with databases for Windows 10 Universal Apps as well as WPF.

I'll try to make my main question more specific by asking the following.

1. What database is best for beginners/small projects to use in WPF, Console Apllication, and UWP projects? Or do I have to use different databases depending on the project?
2. How do I install, configure, and use said database (a small example or reference will suffice)?
3. Where does the EF (Entity Framework) fit into all this?
4. I tried installing EF for a UWP project, but things like `using System.Data.Entity;` couldn't be found. But there was no problem in a Console Application. How come?
5. Are there any good books, blogs, online courses etc. you can recommend to get up to speed on all this database stuff for .NET?

I have already started my education by taking [this entity course on pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/entity-framework-6-getting-started), but it seems that learning about the Entity Framework doesn't necessarily teach me how to set up a database. At least not in this course.

I hope some of you more initiated people can help me out. As you can see, I'm running in circles (sure feels like that) and I hope you can push me in the right direction. A general brain dump on the subject would be more than a sufficient answer.

If I'm not making sense, or if this question just aren't good for SO, please let me know in the comments. I'll clarify and take action as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What database is best for beginners/small projects to use in WPF, Console Apllication, and UWP projects? Or do I have to use different
>      databases depending on the project?

A MySQL database would be ideal, as this is a Windows project and would integrate best with any of those project types. However, for development, you can create a local database as an MDF file. This sort of database is particularly easy to set up and work with as it requires no additional database software or server.

> 2. How do I install said database?

Try following [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx) to setup a local database project in your solution. Once the database project is created, other projects in your solution can easily access it, as shown in [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171890.aspx). The second walkthrough applies to a Windows Forms application, but you could easily apply the same concepts to any other project type.

> 3. Where does the EF (Entity Framework) fit into all this?

Entity Framework provides functionality that makes it easier to interact with and automate actions related to a database, such as retrieving, deleting, or modifying database information. A more in-depth tutorial is provided [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx).

> 4. I tried installing EF for a UWP project, but things like using
>      System.Data.Entity; couldn't be found. But there was no problem in a
>      Console Application. How come?

This may be because your UWP project did not have a proper reference to the Entity Framework. You can add the Entity Framework to your project's references [using NuGet or the Package Manager Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906.aspx).

> 5. Are there any good books, blogs, online courses etc. you can recommend
>      to get up to speed on all this database stuff for .NET?

Microsoft has some [good documentation](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) for learning Entity Framework. [This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) was the one I learned from.

Comment: Thanks for this. I know MySQL, but haven't thought it could work with .NET applications, much less Universal Applications. You get the checkmark, but do note I'll give it to the most elaborate answer present at any given time ;)

Comment: You are a fair yet harsh mistress. ;)